# Scroll text in Windows Taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Is there any way I can make a window in taskbar to scroll its text on windows 10?

Something like Winamp's `Scroll title in the Windows Taskbar`

Answer (score 0):

Only the program in question can scroll the title, because this involves calling
Windows API functions to achieve this effect.

So if the program in question doesn't have this option, or is not open-source
or you can't modify that source, then your only option is to make a feature-request
for that option to its developers.